# Simulating a Bus Journey in a MapActivity

Tags: android, animation, mapactivity, simulate

I am fairly new to Android and am looking for some help.

I have a simple MapActivity and a vector of Stops(lat,long) with an ItemizedOverlay placed on each stop. I know the distance between each stop and the speed at which the bus will be travelling. Seperately using the Haversine formula i can calculate what position(lat,long) the bus will be at after a certain time. I would like to visualize(animate) the journey that would be taken from the first stop to the last stop. My question is what would be the best way to go about doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether that is a good idea but the first thing which came to my mind is to use a TimerTask and update the position of the bus in it (e.g. every second), since you know its position at a certain time.

Everything else seem to me to be hard to realize for an map overlay...

I assume the Bus should also be an ItemizedOverlay right?